# how to simulate a default record for a select in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on a MySQL problem involving alias lookup.  I want a table/view/function/thing where I can look up aliases.  I want it in SQL because I then want to use the output to match records for any of the aliases.

The problem is I want to *implicitely* include all the trivial cases where any IDs not in the table have an Alias of only themselves.  That is, given an ID = 'E' not in the alias table, return an Alias of 'E'.

There are a small number of IDs with multiple Aliases, and a large number of IDs that are only identified by themselves.

A function would work if it could return a list of values, but that doesn't seem possible.  It could return a string of delimited IDs, but I didn't see how to split the string and use the resulting IDs.

I can't get a view to work because I didn't see a way to pass in the target ID we want to look up Aliases for.

For example:

`AliasTbl`

```
ID  Alias
--  -----
A   A
A   B
A   C
B   A
B   B
B   C
C   A
C   B
C   C
```

`RecordTbl`

```
ID  other fields
--  ------------  ...
A   foo
B   bar
C   zot
D   other
E   another
...
```

So if ID = 'B' has aliases 'A', 'B', 'C', I want all three values returned. (Note that I am using the term "alias" loosely to include the ID itself.)

```
SELECT *
FROM RecordTbl
WHERE ID in
      (SELECT Alias
      FROM AliasTbl
      WHERE ID = 'B');
```

...should return...

```
ID  other fields
--  ------------  ...
A   foo
B   bar
C   zot
```

For any value other than 'A', 'B' or 'C'...

```
SELECT *
FROM RecordTbl
WHERE ID in
      ( given any ID do some magic to return the ID as its only Alias );
```

So for ID = 'E', return...

```
ID  other fields
--  ------------  ...
E   another
```

Comment: The answer given above does not look like the same situation described here.

Answer (score 0):

A left join ensures that records not existing in Alias table return a null alias. Then ifnull() function replace null by record ID.

Select record.ID, ifnull(alias.Alias, record.ID)
from RecordTbl as record
left join AliasTbl as alias on record.D = alias.ID

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining this well, but I don't think this is doing what I'm looking for.  The idea is to use the Aliases to filter the RecordTbl.

Comment: I think I may have figured out a way to do what I want.  By using a UNION DISTINCT, I can add a 'fake' record to simulate the trival case: an ID who's only Alias is itself.  I can then use that to filter the RecordTbl  SELECT r.*
FROM RecordTbl r
where 
 ID in
 (SELECT Alias
 FROM AliasTbl a
 WHERE a.ID = 'E'
 UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT 'E'
    FROM dual)
order by r.ID;